# How to get all the path by traversing the framework of neo4j using java

Tags: java, neo4j, frameworks, traversal

So to sum up the days or do calculations on relationship value by modifing the program. This is a basic snippet written by me learning to create a java maven for neo4j.

```
public enum Labels implements Label {
    AIRPORT;
}

public enum Relationships implements RelationshipType {
    FLIGHT;
}                                                      

ResourceIterator<Node> airport = db.findNodes( Labels.AIRPORT );

System.out.println( "AIRPORT:" );
while( airport.hasNext() ) {
    Node airports = airport.next();
    System.out.println( "STATION:\t" + airports.getProperty("STATION") );
}
```